# .exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

struggling to find a solution all over, have latest chrome 117 and also downloaded chromedriver and used the path accordingly in script
also tried with chrome browser

Although it opens the browser but does not opens the desired test url (cnn.com) browser opens and eventually fails with the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\\xx\\x\\x\\chrome-win64\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe
```

what can i try to browser starts opening urls, also tried disabling firewall but no luck

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service_obj = Service(r"C:\\xx\\xx\\xx\\chrome-win64\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe")

driver.get("https://www.cnn.com/")
```

what can i try to open desired urls, also tried disabling firewall but no luck
host file

```
# 102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
# 38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
#::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use these below lines of code, to come out of the latest Chrome issue.

```
 options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--remote-allow-origins=*")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.